# adding a string to an array

Tags: c#

I'm just doing a little project in C# (I'm a beginner), my code is basically asking you "how many words are in this sentence?" and then asks you for every word, once it gets all of them it prints it out with "ba" attached to every word.

I know I'm a real beginner and my code's probably a joke but could you please help me out with this one?

```
Console.WriteLine("How many words are in this sentence?");

int WordAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int i = 1;

while (i <= WordAmount)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a word");
    string[] word = new string[] { Console.ReadLine() };
    i++;
}

Console.WriteLine(word + "ba");
```

Comment: hint look at the `Split` method.

Comment: I don't think you want to create a new `word` array in every single iteration of your `while` loop, yes? Create your array **before** the `while` loop (with an array size that matches the number of iterations of the loop), and then inside the loop just place/set the elements in the array. If you don't know what i mean, it would probably best to spend some time looking into a C# tutorials about arrays...

Comment: Does this code compile? I seems the `word` array scope ends after the closing brace of the while loop also.

Comment: What is your question? You've posted what your code does, then you posted the code, but you haven't stated what problem you're running into.

Comment: You may want to look at the `List<T>` class (in particular `List<string>`).  A `List<string>` is like a `string[]`, except it's not a fixed size.  You create the list, and just `Add` items to it as you need them (without having to get the size right up front, or keep track of indexes).

Comment: @Flydog57 although good advice, in this situation OP wants to specifically learn arrays. It's probably better to make use of that `WordAmount` variable to set a presized array instead.

Comment: Yup, that's why I said "You may want to look at `List<T>`" in a comment, not an answer.  OP is learning.  Learning about collections (in particularly what you can do with Arrays and Lists) is a big part of a beginner's learning.  If I were learning this all over again (and got that advice), I might even do the work once with an array and once with a List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you've just got one issue.

`string[] word = new string[] { Console.ReadLine() };`

You are creating a new array list inside the scope of a while loop. Not only will this disappear every loop, meaning you never save the old words, but you also won't be able to use it outside of the loop, making it useless.

Create a `string[] words = new string[WordAmount];`. Then iterate through it to add your `Console.ReadLine()` to it, and finally, iterate through it once more and `Console.WriteLine(words[i] + "ba");`

Comment: I believe that using List here is out of scope. OP is trying to understand loops and arrays. IList is Iterable but not array

Comment: Changed answer to avoid the complication. Additionally, I also noticed OP had a fixed amount of words specified, so it's better to simply use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] wordList = new string[WordAmount];
while (i <= WordAmount)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a word");
    wordList[i-1] = Console.ReadLine() ;
    i++;
}

foreach (var item in wordList)
    Console.WriteLine(item + "ba");
```

Working Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7UJKwN

your code has multiple issues. First you need to define your array outside of your while loop, and then fill it one by one.

In order to read/write array of strings (string[]), you need to loop through (iterate) it.

My code actually iterates your wordList. In the first While loop I am iterating to fill the wordList array. then printing it in the second loop

Comment: Why did you delete and repost the exact same answer?

Comment: I canged it, but I am really ın hard situation to understand the purpose of your downvote. The code is working. I kept the concept of the code. I have given proper explaination. What is the deal? really

Comment: I haven't voted on your post. That isn't my downvote

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider storing your words in some kind of collection, for example a list.

```
List<string> words = new List<string>();
while (i <= WordAmount)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a word");
    string word = Console.ReadLine();
    words.Add(word);
    i++;
}
```

I don't think your code compiles - the reason is you are trying to use the word variable outside of the scope that it is defined in. In my solution I have declared and initialized a list of strings (so list of the words in this case) outside of the scope where user has to input words, it is possible to access it in the inner scope (the area between curly brackets where user enters the words).

To print all the words, you have to iterate over the list and add a "ba" part. Something like this:

```
foreach(var word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word + "ba");
}
```

Or more concisely:

```
words.ForEach(o => Console.WriteLine(o + "ba"));
```

If you want to print the sentence without using line breaks, you can use LINQ:

```
var wordsWithBa = words.Select(o => o + "ba ").Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
Console.WriteLine(wordsWithBa);
```

Although I would recommend learning LINQ after you are a bit more familiarized with C# :)

You can look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-2/) to familiarize yourself with the concept of collections and scopes of variables.

You could also use a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder) class to do this task (my LINQ method is not very efficient if it comes to memory, but i believe it is enough for your purpose).